# Android Q: file.mkdirs() returns false

Tags: android, android-9.0-pie

We have an app that uses external storage to store some temporary files: images, binary data. The code for that has been working for a few years without big changes until recently. On Android Q it doesn't work:

```
File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + File.separator + MainActivity.APP_DIR)
f.mkdirs();
// do sth with f
```

The `mkdirs` now returns just `false`.

Required permission is provided in the manifest:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

The code works fine on previous versions of Android. Is there some system level change to this type of access? If so, what is the workaround?

Comment: Refer to the following answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50571167/3736063

Answer (score 63, accepted):

There was huge privacy change in android Q by introducing [Scoped Storage](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage#scoped-storage).

Since Q beta 4 it's possible to [opt-out](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/use-cases#opt-out-scoped-storage) of that feature by:

- targeting API 28 (or lower)
- using `requestLegacyExternalStorage`  manifest attribute (while targetting API 29):

---

```
<manifest ... >
  <!-- This attribute is "false" by default on apps targeting Android Q. -->
  <application android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" ... >
    ...
  </application>
</manifest>
```

**edit:** as mentioned in other answer this does not work if app is targeting API 30 - Android 11 devices will ignore legacy storage flag.

**edit 2:** heads up for anyone planning to publish on play store - soon usage of this flag will be restricted (new and updated apps won't be accepted) unless its required for core functionality (e.g. file manager)

Comment: Isn't he asking for Android Pie? But, I think you're addressing Android Q related problems.

Comment: @Toaster you're right, it was late at night when I replied. For some bizzare reason I thought 9 is Q already.

Comment: Haha, that's fine. Just update the answer in your free-time.

Comment: @Pawel Looks like not only you were sleepy, I didn't pay attention - the image I used to check was indeed of Q (9+ emulator). Checked on 9 - all on fine, so re-phrase the question and accept

Comment: @khusrav that's what was on my mind, didn't see a reason why that code wouldn't work on P but knew there'd be an issue on Q.

Comment: @khusrav Well, that was a disaster. :-D

Comment: I've updated my sdk version to 29 and added that attribute but I'm still facing the same issue. Is there anything else that i'm missing? my android version is '10QP1A'

Comment: Yes it works for me i have just added `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` in API 29 or higher

Answer (score 11):

**UPDATE:** Since Android 11 [scoped storage is enforced](https://developer.android.com/preview/privacy/storage#scoped-storage). Apps that target Android 10 (API level 29) can still request the `requestLegacyExternalStorage` attribute. This flag allows apps to temporarily opt-out of the changes associated with scoped storage, such as granting access to different directories and different types of media files. After you update your app to target Android 11, the system ignores the `requestLegacyExternalStorage` flag.

---

In API level 29 direct access to shared/external storage devices is deprecated. When an app targets `Build.VERSION_CODES.Q`, the path returned from `getExternalStorageDirectory()` method is no longer directly accessible to apps.
Apps can continue to access content stored on shared/external storage by migrating to alternatives such as [Context#getExternalFilesDir(String)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)), [MediaStore](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html), or [Intent#ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT).

It's a best practice to use scoped storage unless your app needs access to a file that doesn't reside in the app-specific directory.

Those who face the issue with managing files in Android-Q may read through [this](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/04/22/death-external-storage-more-story.html) article to know further.

Comment: @RonTLV Updated the answer with Android11 developer preview 3 privacy changes.

Answer (score 3):

In the new Android update `API 30` you can only write in your `app-specific files`

```
 File directory = new File(context.getFilesDir(), "YOUR_DIR");
 directory.mkdirs();
```

or in the external storage of your app `Android/data`

```
File directory = new File(myContext.getExternalFilesDir("FolderName"),"YOUR_DIR");
```

UPDATE

this answer provided another solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/65744517/8195076

UPDATE

another way is to grant this permission in `manifest`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

like this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/66968986/8195076