# react-native-fs cannot access storage

Tags: react-native, react-native-fs

i'm using [react-native-fs](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs) package to save files to android storage.

when i perform these two lines of code, it works

```
await RNFS.readDir(RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath);
=====>/data/user/0/com.youtubedljs/files
await RNFS.readDir(RNFS.CachesDirectoryPath);
=====>/data/user/0/com.youtubedljs/cache
```

but when i try to access external storage, like Download or documents files

```
await RNFS.readDir(RNFS.DownloadDirectoryPath);
```

i get this error

**Error: Attempt to get length of null array**

i already granted storage permissions to the application, it didn't work.

**Update:** Works fine on android 8.1, i think that the package doesn't support android 10 yet

Comment: it is related to android Q privacy change : [here is tomporary solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56821320/11616789)

Answer (score 3):

Need to give read-write permissions.

that's okay.. but you also need to get incode permissions, before accessing file

```
import {PermissionsAndroid} from 'react-native';

const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
      PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
    );
    if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
      //alert('You can use the location');
      console.log('write granted');
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.warn(err);
    return false;
  }
```

Comment: i added these two lines, same issue `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

Comment: that's okay.. but you also need to get incode permissions, before accessing file

see my edited reply above

Comment: `const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
      PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
    );
    if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
      await RNFS.readDir(RNFS.DownloadDirectoryPath);
    } else {
      console.log('not granted');
    }`
the access is granted but the error remains **Error: Attempt to get length of null array**

Comment: @AbdelkaderOumrani were you able to fix the issue? I'm also getting this error after upgrading to android x. Would be helpful if you could share the steps to fix this.

Comment: You can’t save the file “statement19May2021.pdf” because the volume “APPLE SSD - Data” is read only Getting this error After try to copy a file in iOS Documents folder

Answer (score 0):

```
First you have to ask for permission 
then you can save the into download folder of mobile
import {request, PERMISSIONS} from 'react-native-permissions';

 request(
      Platform.OS === 'ios'
        ? PERMISSIONS.IOS.MEDIA_LIBRARY
        : PERMISSIONS.ANDROID.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
    ).then(result => {
      console.log(result);
     
      );
    });

 var path = RNFS.DownloadDirectoryPath + '/filename.txt';
```